# multiple emails in an input field in UI5

Tags: javascript, validation, sapui5, email-validation

I have a use case where I want to add multiple email addresses in the `sap.m.Input` field. Is there any way I can do it with keeping type `sap.m.InputType.Email` of the input field?

I have checked that in HTML5, `<input>` tag has `multiple` attribute which allows user to enter multiple values of the given input-type. I want similar thing here.

I want to validate all the email addresses also. So currently I am doing it by splitting the email addresses from the `sap.m.Input` value by semicolons and manually validating each email address from the `sap.m.Input`'s email validator.

```
var oEmails = new sap.m.Input();

onFormSubmit: function(oEmail) {
    var isValidEmails = false;
    var emails = oEmail.getValue().split(";");
    for (var i=0; i<emails.length; i++) {
        var emailValidation = oEmail.getValidator().emailValidation(emails[i]);
        var isInvalidEmail = (emailValidation.valueType === "Error");
        if (isInvalidEmail) {
            showError(oEmail);
            isValidEmails = false;
            break;
        } else {
            isValidEmails = true;
        }
    }
    return isValidEmails;
}
```

I haven't added type of Input in the `oEmails` as it return an error for multiple emails. But I want to use it so Input control should take care of the validation. Is there any better approach to deal with these problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [sap.m.MultiInput](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MultiInput)? It uses tokens for the individual entries but semantically it offers you to enter multiple entries and you can set the type to email, although I have not tried it so far.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, I think they require some list in advance to show as suggestions when liveChange event occurs. I don't have any list of emails in advance. So I don't think `MultiInput` can be a good option.

Comment: Should also be possible without, although with a little work. I built a small proof of concept here: https://plnkr.co/edit/SEYbw8Y8BL0UOY2ssc90?p=preview (press enter after you entered something)

However, this does not directly solve your email problem. You'll need to validate the email also in this example yourself. But I checked, the input type "EMail" also does not contain validation. In the explored SAP provided a custom email type to be used in data binding to validate emails.

InputType only provides a keyboard on mobile devices with @ on the first page.